# How to use a Swift library in a Flutter Application?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, cocoapods

Recently I've developed a native ios library using Swift 5.

This library is being distributed using Cocoapods and now that is done I would like to know if there's any method to use that same library in a Flutter application from Cocoapods and which is the best way to do it.

#### What I've tried so far:

I tried creating a flutter demo app and moving to `/ios` for running `pod init` and later configuring my Podfile to point the source of the Pod and after that I did a `pod install`.
Apparently this works, because if I go to my Runner.xcworkspace and add
`import MyLib`
to the AppDelegate, it compiles.

The thing is, how do I access the methods and classes of the Pod from my Dart code? Is it possible or I have to manage that interaction directly from Swift?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can execute native code via method channel. Check this link - https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: Thank you very much, Anyway I would like to know if there's a simpler way, because the library I need to use is a little big, so if I use the channels method it might take too much time.

Comment: Hi, does my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. You need to manually write down some boilerplate between Swift and Dart. But this can be simplified by some code generators, for example [pigeon](https://pub.dev/packages/pigeon).

If you are using other languages like Rust instead of Swift, there does exist more advanced [code generators](https://github.com/fzyzcjy/flutter_rust_bridge) that requires almost zero boilerplate. But there seems none for Swift.